# Slicing a NumPy array - choose values corresponding to certain indexes

Tags: python, numpy

Is there an easy way to select elements from an array corresponing to certain indexes. Example: suppose I have an array of indexes, IDX = array((3,7,5)) and an array A = array((2,5,3,1,7,5,1,9,7,4,2,5)) from which I would like to select the elements in A corresponding to the indexes given in IDX.

I.e. I'm looking for something like this:

```
A[IDX] = array((1,9,5)) or  
A[3,7,5] = array((1,9,5)).
```

Comment: And the problem with the approach you describe is?

Comment: Sorry - I only tried the bottom line in the code example above (which is not working). The top line i actually working, but the bottom line should be A[array((3,7,5))].

Comment: The last line would be element access for a three-dimensional array.  The first line should work fine, though.  Voting to close.

Comment: Indexing with a Python list works too: `A[[3,5,7]]`.

Comment: Ok, thanks - that will be useful too.

Comment: Why post a question if you didn't even try your own suggestion? The 1st option you suggest works

Answer (score 3):

With Numpy I would do it like this:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> IDX = np.array([3,7,5])
>>> A = np.array([2,5,3,1,7,5,1,9,7,4,2,5])
>>> A[IDX]
array([1, 9, 5])
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't have numpy installed, but with standard python you can use a list comprehension, I guess numpy arrays should not behave very differently:

```
>>> IDX = (3,7,5)
>>> A = (2,5,3,1,7,5,1,9,7,4,2,5)
>>> [A[i] for i in IDX]
[1, 9, 5]
```

Comment: This would work, but it would defeat the whole purpose of NumPy (which is to avoid Python loops in favour of optimised C loops).